# How to set JPanel fixed size such that the JScrollPane (scrolling) appears?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane, preferredsize

I'm working on a little code. `JFrame` containing a `JPanel` with specific dimensions. Here is my code:

```
import javax.swing.*; 
import java.awt.*; 

public class ScrollPane extends JFrame { 

    public ScrollPane() {
        super("Title");
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setSize(320,240);

        JScrollPane scroller = new JScrollPane(new DrawingPane()); 
        scroller.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(320,240)); 

        add(scroller); 
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    } 

    private class DrawingPane extends JPanel {
        public DrawingPane(){
            super();
            setSize(640,480);
            setMinimumSize(new Dimension(320,240));
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ScrollPane();
    } 
}
```

Even with a minimum size set for the `JPanel`, the scrolls don't appear.

Comment: `private class DrawingPane extends JPanel { ..
setSize(640,480);` I'd replace the `DrawingPane` with a `BufferedImage` displayed in a `JLabel`..

Comment: +1 for the _workaround_

Comment: After _overriding_ `getPreferredSize()` as pointed out by @camickr (which IMO should be the accepted answer), call `frame.pack()` instead of `frame.setSize()`. The `pack()` method will take all the preffered sizes of internal components into consideration, then size the frame accordingly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All components are responsible for determining there preferred size so layout managers can work properly. When doing custom painting you need to override the `getPreferredSize()` of your custom component to return the Dimension of your component.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more information and working examples.

Answer (score -1):

You need to set Preferred Size for your Drawing Panel as well:

```
private class DrawingPane extends JPanel {
        public DrawingPane(){
            super();
            setPreferredSize(new Dimension(640,480));
            setMinimumSize(new Dimension(320,240));
        }

    }
```

Comment: -1  You should NOT be using the setPreferredSize() method. Instead you should be overriding the getPreferredSize() method. Don't take shortcuts!!!

Comment: @camickr there are multiple ways of doing things. you might be right but that does not invalidates my answer.

Comment: For those that don't want to stick their head in the sand, see [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Swing?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/418556)  (Yes.)

Comment: @Sanjeev, `there are multiple ways of doing things.` - yes, but the problem is beginners will always take the shortcut, because they think it is easier, not understanding the full implications of the decision.

Comment: @camickr got your point .. please suggest shall i remove this answer?

Comment: I would keep it since the answer is accepted. Andrew's link is good reading for those who want to know more.

Comment: @camickr Now it is not an accepted answer anymore, i am keeping it for Andrew's Link though. thanks